# How to deal with multiple jcheckbox and one jbutton JAVA

Tags: java, button, checkbox

For example I have 2 checkbox and 1 button my code would be like this.

```
private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener
    {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
        if (chckbxNewCheckBox1.isSelected() && chckbxNewCheckBox2.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck1 = 1;
            checkboxcheck2 = 1;

        }
        else if(chckbxNewCheckBox1.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck1 = 1;

        }
        else if(chckbxNewCheckBox2.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck2 = 1;

        }
    }
    }

  private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         if (checkboxcheck1 == 1 && checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
             textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }
         else if(checkboxcheck1 == 1)
            {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
         else if (checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
              textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }
         else
         {
            checkboxcheck1 = 0;
         }
    }   
  }
```

But then what if I have more than 2 checkbox like 10 or more.It would take forever to to make the if statement in CheckBoxHandler and ButtonHandler. Anybody know how to make it work if I have more than 2 checkbox ?
My program is read the file and count the specific character in the file and then display it. The way to display it is click on the checkbox and click the yes button. But it will take forever for me to do the if statement. You guys have any idea? Thanks yall so much for help.

Comment: You would use an array and some loops. You may want to read up on some [basics about Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array of checkboxes like so

```
CheckBox[] checkboxes = new CheckBox[10]; // or JCheckBox if using swing
```

And in the constructor, create them with

```
String[] filenames = { ...  }; // have a list of files?
for(int i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
  // for each box, create and add it to your panel 
  mypanel.add(checkboxes[i]=new CheckBox(filename[i]));
  checkboxes[i].addItemListener(mylistener);
}
```

then in the listener, you can have

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
  boolean state = ((CheckBox)e.getSource()).isSelected();
  // do something with this state if needed
}
```

But notice that you don't actually need the item listeners at all.
In the button listener you can do

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  for (int i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
     if(checkboxes[i].isSelected()){
        // do something with file i
     }
  }
}
```

Note that if your file operation takes time, you have to do the processing in a new thread, not just in the button handler!

Comment: But I already create everything tho. Is Java have any method about listener to hide the textfield and then when i click the checkbox then click the button the textfield will appear ? http://postimg.org/image/f834lwtyf/

Comment: 1) You should not "already create everything though". That is a recipe for a difficult time! The point is that, you should never create variables with numbered names like `checkboxcheck1` etc.

Comment: 2) re: hiding text fields, yes that is straightforward but you should post that as a new question.